# hibernate search criteria for many to many relationship

Tags: hibernate, many-to-many, criteria

I am very new to Hibernate criteria. Currently i hv some requirements that need to create hibernate search criteria for the two entities with many to many relationship between them.

For instance, I have Student and Course objects. A Student can take more than one Course and a course can be taken by more than one Student. The Student and Course classes looks like the following

```
public class Student {
   private String name ;

   private Set<Course> courses = new HashSet<Course>();

   // setter and getters following
}

public class Course{
  private String courseName ;
  // setter and getter following
}
```

I configured uni-directional relationship from Student to Course.

My requirement is to select all the Students based on the course name. For example to select Students who take course name "Math101". As i am very new to hibernate, i am not sure how to do it. can u please show me sample criteria for such requirements? Many thanks.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

```
session.createCriteria(Student.class)
    .createCriteria("courses")
        .add( Restrictions.eq("courseName", "Math101") )
    .list();
```